# My Main function is only asking me for 1 input. How can I get the function to multiply three inputs?

Tags: c

What the program is trying to do is multiply 3 inputs (1.0f/3.0f) from 3 different functions to arrive at the volume of a pyramid. But I'm having trouble with the last function, which is asking me only for 1 input and therefore not multiplying the 3 inputs and (1.0f/3.0f).

```
float volume(float baselength, float baseWidth, float height){
    float frac = (1.0f/3.0f);
    float vol;
    vol = baselength*baseWidth*height*frac;
    return vol;
}
float main(){
    displayTitle();
    float num;

    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num);

    float frac = (1.0f/3.0f);   
    float baselength;
    float baseWidth;
    float height;
    float result;

    result = volume(baselength, baseWidth, height);
    printf("The Volume of the Pyramid is %f",result);
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Welcome to the Pyramid Program
Enter a Number: 5 
Enter a Number: 4
Enter a Number: 3

The Volume of the Pyramid is 20.00
```

but the output is

```
Welcome to the Pyramid Program
Enter a Number: 5
The Volume of the Pyramid is 0.000000
```

Comment: If you have just one query for a number why do you expect it to ask for three numbers? Make it ask for three numbers and go from there. Understand what the pieces you’re copypasting do, don’t just copypaste it since at the moment there’s no relation with the querying and calculating with undefined results.

Comment: `float main()` is wrong

Comment: can we use `float` return type for main function?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are only reading one input.

```
scanf("%f", &num);
```

reads one input and stores it in the variable num, currently your baselength,basewidth and height are all initialised to 0 .You need to execute this three times for three inputs. I have modified your code

```
float volume(float baselength, float baseWidth, float height){
    float frac = (1.0f/3.0f);
    float vol;
    vol = baselength*baseWidth*height*frac;
    return vol;
}
int main(){
    //displayTitle();
    float num;
    float frac = (1.0f/3.0f);   
    float baselength;
    float baseWidth;
    float height;
    float result;

    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%f", &baselength);
    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%f", &baseWidth);
    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%f", &height);


    result = volume(baselength, baseWidth, height);
    printf("The Volume of the Pyramid is %f",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Ps its always int main and it should always return 0

Comment: Don't forget fflush(stdin)

Comment: The return statement is optional for `main`, exceptionally (assumed to be 0 if missing and compatible with `int` – C99 and up). The return value does not have to be `0` either.

Comment: Technically the return 0 is used to indicate that the file has executed correctly, so for good programming practice I would recommend it

Comment: I like to see `return 0;` at the end of `main()` when everything has gone smoothly.  If something has gone wrong, the code in `main()` should either use `return EXIT_FAILURE;` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or use some other non-zero value (between 1 and 255) to indicate that it failed.  You can also use a variable that is set to indicate failure and return (or exit) with that.

Comment: "currently your baselength,basewidth and height are all initialised to 0" is incorrect: they aren't initialised at all.

Comment: Um the default initial value of float is 0.000000, isnt it?

Comment: @akshaykishore No default value. They will have some junk values.

Comment: Only if they are static.